# Is there a single word for "Making a mistake just to make a point"

Tags: single-word-requests

Google Chrome released an improved spell check option today. This is how the feature is described:

[image: bettar spell chek]

> Chrome as auto-updated with bettar spell chek. Try the "Ask Google for Suggestions" feature in the right click menu of any text area.

As you see, *bettar* and *chek* are deliberately misspelled just to make the point. Is there a single word or phrase to describe this?

(I couldn't think of a better title. Feel free to edit)

Comment: The point made is that it's April Fool's Day.

Comment: Having written a 150-page thesis on the rhetorical uses of irony, I'd say what you have here is a fairly obvious and weakly ironic attempt at persuading you to check out chrome.  Did it work on you?  Personally, I resisted.

Comment: Mistakes are *made*, never *done*.

Comment: @tchrist I did not know that. Maybe a influence of my mother tongue. Updated title. (thanks!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Cacography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography) is:

> deliberate comic misspelling, a type of humour similar to malapropism.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a word for this exact meaning.  However, it falls within the realm of *parody*, for sure.  Google defines a parody as:

> An imitation of the style of a particular writer, artist, or genre
>   with deliberate exaggeration for comic effect.

In this case, the style or "artists" in question are "people who don't use spell-check and misspell simple words."

Comment: “Tongue-in-cheek” might apply.

Answer (score 1):

In UK English, the phrase "spot the deliberate mistake" is common.

It implies the context of a teacher who makes a mistake on purpose so that the students can try to spot and correct it.

Nowadays it's more often used as a sort of "oops" exclamation when someone makes an actual mistake.